# Почему после использования cin функции cin.get() и cin.getline() не работают, а последующие вызовы cin срабатывают?

Tags: c++, get, cin, getline

Насколько я знаю cin оставляет символ `'\n'` в потоке из-за чего последующие вызовы `cin.get()` и `cin.getline()` не будут срабатывать, поскольку они будут натыкаться на символ перевода строки и завершать свою работу. Для того, чтобы функции `cin.get()` и `cin.getline()` успешно работали после `cin >>` нужно "выбросить" `'\n'` из потока при помощи `cin.get()` или `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')`.
**Вопрос: почему cin будет работать и без "очищения" потока от символа '\n'?**
Т.е. я имею в виду, что этот код будет работать без cin.get() или cin.ignore():

```
    char str1[80], str2[80];
    cin >> str1;
    cin >> str2;
```

А этот нет:

```
    char str1[80], str2[80];
    cin >> str1;
    cin.getline(str2, 80);
```

Если я как-то непонятно изложил суть проблемы, говорите)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`operator >>` производит чтение с разделением по пробельным символам и при вызове будет сначала пропускать эти символы, пока не дойдет до текста. `getline` производит чтение до конца строки.

Comment: Т.е. нажатие клавиши Enter при чтении с помощью cin воспринимается как пробел?

Comment: @JustLearn да, на экране же он не отображается

Comment: не совсем понимаю. Ведь cin оставляет символ \n в потоке, а не пробел.

Comment: @JustLearn `\n` - это пробельный символ, также как и собственно проблел

Comment: Из-за символа \n впоследствии не может быть производен ввод с помощью cin.get() и cin.getline(). Но при этом если заменить cin.get() (getline()) на cin, то все будет работать. Почему?

Comment: "\n - это пробельный символ, также как и собственно пробел" - разве?

Comment: Я не могу нигде найти про это информацию. Набираю, что такое \n в c++ единственное, что удается найти это то, что \n символ новой строки

Comment: @JustLearn Пробельные символы определяются как в функции [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace). Их куда больше, чем только пробел.

Comment: cin не оставляет символ \n в потоке, а оставляет в буфере, и  \n не пробельный символ, а символ разделитель, также как и пробел

Comment: Мне в другой теме помогли с этим, и я понял о чем Вы говорите

Comment: operator >> пропускает все пробельные символы,  символы табуляции, новой строки и только после этого начинает чтение

Comment: @JustLearn Пробельные символы включают в себя символы табуляции и новой строки.